# Entity framework slow to connect to database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ImgSimContext>());

using (var db = new ImgSimContext())
{
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
    db.Database.Initialize(force: true);

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Booted in {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

This takes about 2 seconds, even when the database has already been created. Is there any way I can speed it up?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EF6, then it is a known issue as described here:
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1749