# Speed up entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been looking to optimize a web application which uses MVC 2 and EF4. Listing queries took ~22seconds for ~10k rows with 14 columns, which is obviously too slow.

So as part of this I've upgraded to MVC 4 and EF 6.1 (highest I could go with VS2010).

For read-only queries I've added .AsNoTracking() to the queries, this dropped the time to ~3seconds. I'm wondering if there's anything more I could do to get it down to ~1seconds.

my code so far is:

```
category = CategoryHelper.MapToOldFormat(category);
var mainIds = Repository.Categories
               .Include(o => o.LinkedCategories)
               .Where(o => o.Category1.Contains(category))
               .AsNoTracking()
               .ToList();
var linkedCats = mainIds.SelectMany(o => o.LinkedCategories).Union(mainIds).Select(c => c.Id);

var notifications = Repository.Notifications
                .Include(o => o.Country)
                .Include(o => o.NonEUCountries)
                .Include(o => o.Language)
                .Include(o => o.RAW)
                .Include(o => o.RAW.Classification)
                .Include(o => o.RAW.TransactionPN)
                .AsNoTracking();

if (id != null)
{
    notifications = notifications.Where(o => o.Id == id);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(category))
{
    notifications = notifications.Where(o => linkedCats.Contains(o.RAW.Classification.CategoryID));
}

return notifications.Logged(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).ToList();
```

In the benchmarks category wand id were null, so the IN for category doesn't get generated. I will be replacing that with a intflag in the future as a fast way to support multiple categories.

Are there any other big performance problems with this example query?

Comment: use the EF Profiler (http://hibernatingrhinos.com/Products/EFProf) to see more details about slow queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework slow to connect to database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222789/entity-framework-slow-to-connect-to-database). There seems to be a list of performance issues with EF 6.1.

Comment: @PatrickHofman that possible duplicate talks about startup performance. I've run my benchmarks multiple times to lower the impact of that on my tests. So I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Okay. It seems broader than just start-up performance.

Comment: @magicandre1981 is there a free tool? from just executing the sql I see in the sql server perf tools itself it seems fast enought.

Comment: Are you benchmarking on a live server? I've seen a noticeable difference between running the site on IISExpress (as localhost) and a deployed site.

Comment: this EF profiler is the best tool I found. I don't know if there is a free tool

Comment: @TiesonT. I was benchmarking using the build in VS Webserver. Production would probably be faster yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, listing 10k results is painful. You need to use paging with large datasets.

Imagine the cost of moving relational data to 10k instances of some class and inject run-time features like self-tracking or lazy-loading. A loop of 10k iterations where each iteration has complex code. It should be slow by default, shouldn't it?

Thus, it seems that you need to leverage LINQ's extension methods [like `.Skip(...)` and `.Take(...)`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx)

Another improvement would be a result of analyzing your current data schema in your DB and your object model, because *1 table is 1 class* (with 14 columns / properties) could be a problem: maybe a segmented design would improve your scenario.

Anyway, paging will be your friend. This should reduce query times to a fraction of a second.

### Update

@Phyx said in some comment:

> I Inherited the project and don't have the budget to change ALL the
>   listings.

If you can't change that, [I would say *caching* should be the solution](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/performance-and-traffic/15-caching-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-website). 1 user should receive the impact of these unoptimized (non-optimizable...) queries and the rest would be consuming an output cache that might last in small time intervals, but it might be enough to speed up your application and reduce load times.

Comment: @TomTom I'm not absolutely sure about that six entities. Check those property names. They don't sound like an association, but who knows...

Comment: @TomTom I take offense to being called Clueless. You don't know the first thing about me, who the hell are you to call me clueless. Also if you learn to read you'd notice that I never blamed EntityFramework. I'm well aware paging would be a better option, but I Inherited the project and don't have the budget to change ALL the listings.

Comment: Use PagedList.Mvc: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList . Implement Paging like this answer suggests. Problem solved.

Comment: @Phyx I've updated my answer with another approach (caching...).

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks, Adding caching to the listing was my next step. I'll move it up the list of things to try. Thanks.